# Why can't I type into datepicker textbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker

I tweaked little bit how datetime picker works. It is triggered on change of select.

But now I cannot type into the text box. I use the text box not only for date time but to let user input other type of information in my application.

**How can I make user to type into this text box?** So all other settings stay as it is. Datepicker is triggered only on select change. Not on clicking the textbox itself.

[jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/dPRjS/8/)

html code

```
<input id="datetime" type="text" name="datetime" value="" >
<select size=5>
    <option value="not">Not this one</option>
    <option value="not">Not this one</option>
    <option value="not">Not this one</option>
    <option value="datetimepicker">Select date and time</option>
</select>​
```

javascript code

```
$('#datetime').datetimepicker({
    showOn: "button",
});
$('option[value=datetimepicker]').click(function() {
    $('#datetime').datetimepicker('show');
});
​
```

css code

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger{display:none;}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This your code disable your INPUT by default and make datetimepicker "button" from it, that why you can't print text inside INPUT field:

```
$('#datetime').datetimepicker({
    showOn: "button",
});
```

Let's look further:

```
$('option[value=datetimepicker]').click(function() {
  // This part of code will work when you click inside SELECT field
}
```

So, you need to transform your input into datetimepicker when you click inside SELECT, true?

To do this, you just move inicialization of datetimepicker inside previouse block:

```
$('option[value=datetimepicker]').click(function() {
    $('#datetime').datetimepicker({
        showOn: "button",
    });
    $('#datetime').datetimepicker('show');
});
```

Now you can type inside input, untill SELECT was pressed. When SELECT was pressed, datapicker starts and your text in INPUT field disappear.

Here is modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dPRjS/9/

---

### UPDATED:

To add possibility to edit INPUT after datetimepicker was closed, you need to destroy created datetimepicker on field INPUT, to return it to possibility work as INPUT:

You need to activate this action when you click on INPUT field:

```
$('#datetime').click(function(){
     $('#datetime').datetimepicker( "destroy" );
 });
```

Working updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dPRjS/10/

Comment: OK I can type text before I initiate datetime picker but I cannot type text after the datetime picker was used. Any idea on that?

Comment: IE does not support option tag events. Use select `change` event and check the value instead

Comment: Works for me in ff11 and latest chrome. Thank youuuuuu.